# Order of convergence/convergence rate of variant of Newton's Method

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, rate-of-convergence

> $x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{f(x_n)^2 f''(x_n)}{f'(x_n)^3}$

For obtaining the formula above, I did the following:

$f(x_n+ \Delta x_n) \approx f(x_n) + f'(x_n)\Delta x_n + \frac{f''(x_n)}{2} (\Delta x_n )^2 \iff -\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \approx \Delta x_n + \frac{f''(x_n)}{2 f'(x_n)} (\Delta x_n )^2 
\iff -\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \approx \Delta x_n + \frac{f''(x_n)}{2 f'(x_n)} (- \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} )^2 \iff -\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \approx \Delta x_n + \frac{f''(x_n)f'(x_n)^2}{2 f'(x_n)^3}   \iff  \Delta x_n \approx -\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} -\frac{f''(x_n)f'(x_n)^2}{2 f'(x_n)^3}   $

Now my goal is to determine its order/rate of convergence.

I wrote that:

$\Delta x_{n+1} = x - x_{n+1} = x - (x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{f(x_n)^2 f''(x_n)}{f'(x_n)^3}$), but can't find a way to write it in other useful form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the [Euler-Chebyshev method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709283/why-does-chebyshevs-method-have-cubic-convergence), closely related to the likewise third order Halley method.